# Passportjs custom callback - 'Incorrect password' message

Tags: node.js, passport.js

For a regular authentication, the 'Incorrect password' message is available via failureFlash

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

But if I use a custom callback, how can I access that 'Incorrect password' message and show it to the user ? Because the custom callback only seems to check for (!user). I need custom callback as I am doing login via ajax and I cannot have redirects.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.status(401).send({"ok": false}); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return return res.send({"ok": true});
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: `failureFlash`'s functionality is actually provided by the [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) module so if you plan to implement it manually you can use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is in the `info` parameter in your custom callback handler making it very easy to access and send to the user.

On a side not, I wouldn't specify if the username or the password was the cause of the login failure. Using that kind of response it is very easy to test which usernames exist, and then just focus on the password.

Comment: Thanks again for responding. I tried checking the value of `info` in the custom callback handler, but it is `undefined`. Also, I take your other point on not being so specific on username or password (I was inspired by hotmail.com, which still is specific)

Comment: @KayaToast that's weird, it should be there. Did even a little test app https://gist.github.com/vesse/cd57e1695a2ce5852fa6 that does nothing but return the message returned from authenticate to the caller, and the message certainly is there.

Comment: Your example address the question. I must be doing something else wrong (which I'll check, but I guess is probably not related to my specific question). Thanks.